# testbench help to make one clock cycle delay

Tags: vhdl

Can anyone please help me to write a testbench for it?

- Set `load = 1` when you input "a".
- Wait for 1 clock cycle (i.e. the time period of the clock).
- Set `load = 0` and input `a = 00000`

I do not understand how to make 1 clock cycle delay.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it synchronously, rather than waiting for "time periods":

```
process
begin
  load <= '1';
  -- setup other signals as you wish also
  wait until rising_edge(clk);
  load <= '0';
  -- more signals and wait for rising_edge() calls in here...
  wait; -- when you've finally finished.
end;
```

Another useful trick is to have a signal called `finished`. Set is to `0` at the start of your process and to `1` just before the final `wait`.

Then your clock generator can be:

```
signal clk : std_logic := '1';
....
clk <= not clk after clk_period/2 when finished /= '1' else '0';
```

This creates a clock signal which runs until `finished` goes to `1` then stays low.  The simulator will spot there are no further signal changes scheduled and automatically halt.

You can have lots of different processes creating different inputs and checking the outputs.  If each of them sets finished to `1` when they've done, the clock will run until they are all finished due to the resolution function causing the `finished` signal to be `X` until all the drivers are `1`s.

Comment: I changed 'wait for' to 'wait until', because 'wait for' is for time type.

Comment: @Hadi: Thanks - that's been wrong for quite a long time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it that way:

```
SIGNAL CLKp :time := 40 ns;

PROCESS
BEGIN
    CLK <= '0'; wait for CLKp/2;
    CLK <= '1'; wait for CLKp/2;
END PROCESS;

PROCESS
BEGIN
    load <= '1'; a <= ...; wait for CLKp;
    load <= '0'; a <= X"0"; wait for CLKp;
END PROCESS;
```

In that simple example you get 1 cycle delay by using `wait for CLKp`.

Comment: There is no need to make CLKp a signal : a constant is better suited to the purpose (unless you are varying the clock speed during the simulation!)

Comment: It would be better to synchronize using an edge of clk as demonstrated by @MartinThompson.  "Wait for CLKp" only works when you have an open loop test.  As soon as you coordinate with a signal from the DUT, such as ready or acknowledge, you no longer know exactly where in the clock cycle you are at and "Wait for CLKp" is no longer useful.